# Can't post request with array parameter from vue to controller with axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to pass an array from my vue to my controller with axios post. But if I want to get the data from the request I don't get it with array format.

I tried it with an object also `JSON.stringyfy()` too.

The vue data I want to send

```
parts: [],
```

the axios post

```
const config = {
    headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
};

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', this.title);
formData.append('description', this.intro);
formData.append('parts[]', this.parts);
formData.append('pictures', this.selectedPictures);
formData.append('options', JSON.stringify(this.options));
valid = true;
if (valid) {
    axios.post('/admin/oefeningen/oefening-opslaan', formData, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.data);
        });
}
```

Controller

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    try {
        //get request info
        return response($request->input('parts'));
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response($exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Vue data I'm passing

```
parts = ["sdfsdfsdf", "sdfsdfsdfsfsdf"]
```

Result from response

```
sdfsdfsdf,sdfsdfsdfsfsdf (as string, not as array)
```

append for loop

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', this.title);
formData.append('description', this.intro);

for (let i = 0; i < this.parts.length; i++) {
    formData.append('parts', this.parts[i]);
}
```

I want to get the exact data in my controller as I have in my vue component. Like an array I can loop through.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't good. Can't you use json type in the header? Axios will convert arrays to json for you. Also, Request will convert it back. You can work with arrays on both ends and json will be in the middle.

Comment: I remove a response which was out of subject: of course in a post you can pass json in the body.

Comment: Tried it with json type. Just gives me a string as request input in my controller. hmm..

Comment: Did you use a proper header for the post?

Comment: headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}

Comment: ok, also, the variable name has to be parts,  not parts[], I think. Try that please. Also, try to send a simple array to your controller. Just send formData = ['a' : 'A', 'b' : 'B']. I wonder what you get

Comment: it passes the array right now, thank you!

Comment: Great! I am happy it worked.